# git stash merge into master branch

Tags: git, git-merge, tortoisegit

I'm knew to git and using TortoiseGit and Visual Studio Code.
I try to achieve the following, but wasn't able to and didn't find solutions on the web yet:
2 branches: master and daily-backups
daily-backups as the name implies should store a daily status.
The master branch however should not contain all commits of the daily-backups branch after merging, but only milestones.
So I wanted to have the following structure:

```
Master:         m1 - - - - - - - - m2 - - - - - m3...
daily-backups:    \- b1 - b2 - b3 /  \- b4 - b5 /
```

I tried it with the activated squash option in the TortoiseGit Merge command.
After commiting this to the repo I got the following:

```
Master:         m1 - - - - - - - - stashed-commit
daily-backups:    \- b1 - b2 - b3
```

but b3 isn't "linked" to the stashed-commit, although they contain identical code.
Is there a way to achieve this?
Also this seems a bit messy, as when I try to use daily-backups afterwards. I get an merge conflict at the next merge into the master branch.

I already tried doing a normal merge (without stashed option) afterwards, but this includes all
daily-backup commits into the master branch.

Any suggestions?

Comment: i’m not sure what the activated squash option is, but if you do a simple merge commit, it is one commit containing the changes of all the commits in the branch since the last merge. Seems to me to be exactly what you want.

Comment: @xsquared: But a simple merge would create
`m1-b1-b2-b3` and not `m1-m2` so all commits from the daily-backup branch would be visible in the master branch as well.

Comment: How do you expect git to “link” the commit to b3 but only show m1-m2? A link means that it is an ancestor in history and that ancestor has other ancestors, b2 and then b1. git would be broken if the history didn’t reflect that.

Comment: As an aside, I don't think it's a good idea to try to use Git as a *backup* system. (This is an opinion, not a technical argument, so it's not really appropriate for StackOverflow. But I think it's reasonable as a comment, at least. :-) )